# Angular.js default form error msg style/css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an angular site which has the default form validation, i added the ngMessages module to implement my own messages.
The thing is the site is using the default style for the error messages on the form.

I tried to search for it online but couldn't find it.

[image]

Does anybody know how I pop up this type of message?

Comment: This is a browser message, depending on which browser you are using. It will appear on input boxes with the `required` attribute

Comment: @devqon a `required` attribute check for some value in. but an `email` input type check for "some" email validation.

Comment: Apologies, I meant among others the `required` attribute. Also the `type="email"` etc. as @Hacketo stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default errors validation for HTML5 forms. if you want to remove this you can add **novalidate** attribute to the form tag like this:

```
<form novalidate>

// your content

</form>
```

You cant change the style of this built in errors, so get rid of them and use ng messages to show the errors how you want.

Comment: tnx. i thought its an angular directive that i couldnt find.